# Is intersection of a subtype and its supertype the same as the subtype?

Tags: typescript, set-intersection

Given the following TypeScript code:

```js
interface A { /* ... */ }
interface B extends A { /* ... */ }

type Mystery = A & B;
```

Objects of the `Mystery` type should have all the properties of `A` and all the properties of `B` because it is an intersection type. Objects of type `B` should already have all the properties of `A` because `B extends A`.

Given these definitions, is there a difference between type `Mystery` and type `B`?

Comment: They are conceptually the same but it’s possible for the compiler to treat them differently depending on the specifics of `A` and `B`.  Especially with methods or call signatures, since intersections can be seen as overloads which may affect callability.  Do you have any specific examples you care about?

Comment: Actually I do. This is the context: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file/pull/308/files#

But could you please provide a minimal example of when they would be treated differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a first approximation, if `B extends A`, then `A & B` and `B` are the same.  The compiler will even consider `A & B` and `B` mutually assignable:

```
function foo<A, B extends A>(u: B, m: A & B) {
  u = m; // okay
  m = u; // okay
}
```

although not identical:

```
function foo<A, B extends A>(u: B, m: A & B) {    
  var v: B;
  var v: A & B; // error, not considered identical
}
```

---

In practice there are going to be situations in which the compiler treats `A & B` and `B` differently. Some of these are compiler implementation details that are seen as bugs or design limitations; I'd have to go digging for these.

But one specific place where `A & B` and `B` could easily be different has to do with how intersections of call signatures are interpreted as [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) functions which can be called in multiple ways, whereas extensions of interfaces with call signatures tend to just *override* the parent interface call signature and can only be called one way.   For example:

```
interface A { method(p: any): void }
interface B extends A { method(): void }
```

This is allowed because [functions of fewer parameters are assignable to functions of more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  The type `B` only sees the zero-argument method, so you get the following behavior:

```
declare const a: A;
a.method(0); // okay
declare const b: B;
b.method(); // okay
b.method(0); // error!
```

Since `method()` is overridden in `B`, `b.method()` with no arguments is an error (even though a zero-arg method is assignable to a multi-arg method, you still cannot intentionally call a function with too many arguments without a warning).

Compare this to the intersection:

```
type Mystery = A & B;
declare const m: Mystery;
m.method(""); // okay
m.method(); // okay
```

If you inspect `m.method`, you'll see that it has two overloads:

```
// 1/2 method(p: any): void 
// 2/2 method(): void
```

and therefore can be called in either of the two ways.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7ILYTACwHsATACgAcAuZOEATwEpqA3Q4Y5AXwChRJZEKAELIIAD0ghiAZzSYceImSbJW7Lt24wAriARhghEMhiFCAHlQAaZCPGSZaAHylt1ITezV0AMlsNMTWRkbWQAXhwAbmQAehjkQgBrODpuYOxwkOi4hOTUtNU4KFV3SILmIpK5PyFs+OgoQigbEEIwZAQjaXZoCA4e8GAEOAAbTR5NYggEEaKUTpBpdrhvMrgAOlwCElIABgY63JTuKZm5jq72gCNS7ivNxR2D2Pik4-utpT3nnIamgEJNGA6OQUABZOhLaB0TK+WxlU6zKDzS44agQqFQOhlHIARhiACYFNsyFQaPQVGoONwcgTCcSvpS2MRuNgHiTSAAiTk-V55VnsxmHN50IA)

Comment: The distinction between **override** and **overload** was especially helpful. Thank you for the thorough answer!